# GCC Compiling via. Java API

Tags: java, gnu

I have been searching Google for some kind of API that II could compile a C program but have been pulling up blanks... Any ideas? I could write my own but would rather use an API if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this recent presentation on libclang then jump on the clang/lvm mailing lists and see if you can help out.

http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/Gregor-libclang.pdf

Comment: @codemeh.com so write a JNI wrapper around the current C/C++ API?

Comment: My question was if there was one already... I offered making my own and I am going to have to.

Comment: @cdog5000 you have the choice for either "just" compiling, i.e. running "gcc" from a spawned shell which should be easy enough to implement, or the full functionality of a compiler library that libclang provides and writing a wrapper for that.  Two different things.